# how to plot iteration number

Tags: loops, for-loop, matlab-figure

I have a function code to find number root as follows:

```
function out = New_Sqrt(A,x0,alpha)
N=0;    
for i=alpha
    x=1./(1.+alpha).*(alpha.*x0+A./x0);
    while abs(x.^2-A)>1e-6
        x=1./(1.+alpha).*(alpha.*x0+A./x0);
        x0=x;    
        N=N+1;           
    end        
    N    
    x    
end
```

`A` is an arbitrary positive integer number that we want to find its root. `x0` is our initial guess for root. `alpha` is a weight and important for me. for different values of `alpha`, the iteration number also will be different. So i want to set `alpha=0.1:0.1:2` and then plot the iteration number versus `alpha`, but i don't know how.

How can I store iteration number in a vector for different `alphas`? Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't `N` already what you are talking about? Plotting `N` vs `alpha` is not what you want?

Comment: yes. i'm gonna plot N versus alpha